# Are any airlocks automatic?

Tags: docking-port

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164637/what-measures-to-put-in-place-to-reduce-airlock-being-used-as-an-execution-chamb) about future fictional airlocks and their automated opening systems made me wonder.

Are there any current (or past) real airlocks where either door can be opened automatically, by which I mean opened by pushing a button rather than turning a mechanical locking device?

Specifically are there any where the outer door (one potentially opening to vacuum) which can be operated by someone not physically adjacent to the door?

Comment: You (or the OP of that question) might want to consider air locks used in underwater systems like submarines and underwater construction projects.  Where the "outside" is deep water, not vacuum, but similarly lethal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The outer hatch of the airlock in the Japanese Experiment Module (JEM) of the International Space Station (ISS) can be operated electrically.

Note that this particular airlock is designed to move equipment, not personnel, in and out of the ISS. The maximum size of an item that can pass through this airlock is 576 mm x 830 mm x 800 mm.

> The outer hatch can be opened and closed electrically, but the inner
>   hatch is operated by hand. There are two ways to operate the outer
>   hatch electrically, auto mode and manual mode. The auto mode performs
>   the hatch opening and closing procedures automatically when a crew
>   member pushes a button. The manual mode is executed by a crew member
>   confirming each individual step by pushing a button. Also, the outer
>   hatch is designed to be operated by hand when electric power is not
>   available.

Source: http://iss.jaxa.jp/iss/kibo/develop_status_07_e.html

The rectangular outer door of the airlock is indicated in this prelaunch photo of the JEM in the shuttle's payload bay.

[image]

Photo credit NASA, annotation mine

Here is a schematic of the airlock.

[image]

Reference: https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/iss-nanoracks-services

Comment: Interestingly, that airlock is large enough for a person, but not one in a spacesuit.

Comment: ...so an absolutely perfect execution chamber then.